# Is it suitable to delete my log.django file?

Tags: python, django, unix

My `log.django` file is over 100,000 lines now. If I delete it, will it be re-generated again? It exists because I have `LOGGING` in my `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'log.django',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Log file cannot be re-generated. It consists of events that occurred in the past. But if you deleted it, a new one will be generated.

I suggest you set [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) logging handler, the maximum size for the log file and a number of backups to be kept. This way once the file reaches maximum size, current log file will be renamed and a new log file will be created.

Django uses [dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema) scheme for logging configuration. For rotating file handler with maximum size of about 2MB and 2 backup log files, you'd define `file` key in `handlers` as:

```
'file': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
    'filename': 'log.django',
    'maxBytes': 2000000,
    'backupCount': 2
 },
```

This way current `log.django` will be renamed to log.django.1 once it reaches size of 2.000.000 bytes and 2 backup files will be kept (log.django.1 and log.django.2) at all times.

If you add `maxBytes` and `backupCount` to your current configuration, your current log file will be renamed to log.django.1 and a new log.django will be created.